# When can you drop an inequality term when you have more than two?

Tags: general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces

I am working on a problem:

> $d$ and $d'$ are metric equivalents on a set $X$, meaning there exist $n > 0, n' > 0$ such that for all $x, y \in X$, $d(x,y) \leq n \cdot d'(x,y)$, $d'(x,y) \leq n' \cdot d(x,y)$. Prove a subset $A$ is open in $(X, d) \iff A$ open in $(X, d')$.

So for one direction, if $A$ open in $(X, d)$, then for all $x \in A$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x) = \{ y \in X : d(x,y) < \epsilon \} \subset A$. Using the given definition $d(x,y) \leq n d'(x,y)$, and the fact that the neighborhood condition is $d(x,y) < \epsilon$, we see that

$$d(x,y) \leq n d'(x,y) < \epsilon$$

At this point I want to make the claim that because $n > 0$, then $n d'(x,y) < \epsilon \iff d'(x,y) < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$.

If so, then if I take an arbitrary point $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x) = \{ y \in X : d(x,y) < \epsilon \} \subset E$, then also this point is $y \in N_{\frac{\epsilon}{n}}(x) = \{ y' \in X : d'(x,y) < \frac{\epsilon}{n} \} \subset E$, and this proves that $E$ is open in $(X, d')$.

However, in the inequality $d(x,y) \leq n d'(x,y) < \epsilon$ from earlier, I "dropped" the $d(x,y)$ part of the inequality when making the assertion that $n d'(x,y) < \epsilon \iff d'(x,y) < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$. If I didn't then I would have something like: $d(x,y) \leq n d'(x,y) < \epsilon \iff \frac{1}{n} d(x,y) \leq d'(x,y) < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$, but then I don't have $\frac{1}{n} d(x,y)$ in my first neighborhood of $B_{\epsilon}(x) = \{ y \in X : d(x,y) < \epsilon \}$, because of that extra $\frac{1}{n}$ factor. Which inequality is the valid way to do this?

Comment: If you're asking if $a\leq b\leq c$ implies $b\leq c$, then yes; "$a\leq b\leq c$" exactly means "$a\leq b$ and $b\leq c$" (you can replace $\leq$ with $<$ as you see fit, of course)

Comment: @Hayden Can $a \leq b \leq c$ imply $a \leq b$ and $bd \leq cd$?

Comment: Well, $b\leq c$ implies $bd\leq cd$ if $d\geq 0$, so yes.

Comment: @Hayden One more: can $a \leq b < c$ imply $a < c$ and $bd < cd$ (if $d > 0$)?

Comment: Yes, transitivity implies $a<c$, and then the same idea as my previous comment says that $a\leq b<c$ implies $b<c$, which implies $bd<cd$ for $d>0$.

Comment: @Hayden Just to be clear, "$a \leq b < c$" can mean "$a < c$ and $bd < cd$" (not separately, but at the same time)

Comment: There's actually no distinction between the two: if something implies two separate things, then it implies their conjugation (i.e. "and").

Answer (score 0):

In the direction you are trying to show, you know by definition of the neighborhood in $(X,d)$ that for all $y\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$, $d(x,y)<\epsilon$. You want to show $A$ is open in $d'$, hoping that for all $y$ in the ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ above, $d'(x,y)<\epsilon$. The usual way to do this is to bound $d'(x,y)$ in terms of $d(x,y)$, and then use the bound on $d(x,y)$, i.e., we chain two inequalities together rather than chop a chain apart. In this case $d'(x,y)\le n'd(x,y)<n'\epsilon$. Almost there, but not the $\epsilon$ we want. This means that the ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is too large to fit in a neighborhood of $x$ in $(X,d')$. Again the usual way to fix this is replace all the $\epsilon$'s before by $\epsilon/n'$, i.e., we start over with a smaller ball $B_{\epsilon/n'}(x)$, and show that for all $y$ in *that* ball, $d'(x,y)<\epsilon$. The same calculation as above will get you there.

Comment: If you start over with $y \in B_{\epsilon/n'}(x), d(x,y) < \epsilon/n'$, then we want to show $d'(x,y) < \epsilon/n'$. In this case we have $d'(x,y) \leq n'd(x,y) < \epsilon$, so $d'(x,y) < \epsilon$, but we have to show $d'(x,y) < \epsilon/n'$, not $d'(x,y) < \epsilon$. So we can't just keep starting over, can we?

Comment: Reworded the answer a little. Hope now it's clearer.